# How to make Networkx Hopcroft Karp matching always give the same result when there are multiple valid solutions?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I have two lists of things, and another one with all the edges of the graph. There are multiple solutions for maximal matching, that's just how the data is. But every time I run the networkx function, it gives me a different matching. I don't care for any particular solution, I'd just like that it sticks to the same one every time I run it.

I've tried looking into the source code for the algorithm but I don't see anything that obviously explains the randomness (granted, I'm rather unexperienced).

This is the relevant code, nothing really fancy going on so I assume it's got to do with networkx's function. Both lists of nodes are sorted and don't change between executions. Sorting the edges list doesn't work either.

```
G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from(top_nodes,bipartite = 1)
G.add_nodes_from(bot_nodes,bipartite = 0)
G.add_edges_from(edges)

pos0 = nx.drawing.layout.bipartite_layout(G, top_nodes, align='vertical', scale=4, center=None, aspect_ratio=4)

matches = bipartite.matching.hopcroft_karp_matching(G,top_nodes)
```

Some extra info. My top_nodes list has 53 anime titles, and the top_nodes has 64 categories that each anime can fit into (no restriction on the amount of animes matched to a category or vice versa). The edges list is a list of tuples that define which anime fits in which category.

I've run it three times to be sure, and used a simple for loop to print each matched pair in different lines. These are the first few results of each attempt:

Attempt 1:

```
2.43: Seiin Koukou Danshi Volley-bu---15
86---18
86 Special Edition: Senya ni Akaku Hinageshi no Saku---84
Beastars---24
Bishounen Tanteidan---110
```

Attempt 2:

```
2.43: Seiin Koukou Danshi Volley-bu---15
86---18
86 Special Edition: Senya ni Akaku Hinageshi no Saku---3
Beastars---55
Beastars 2nd Season---17
```

Attempt 3:

```
2.43: Seiin Koukou Danshi Volley-bu---103
86---120
86 Special Edition: Senya ni Akaku Hinageshi no Saku---84
Beastars---93
Beastars 2nd Season---65
```

All the results are correct, but each time it gives a different one. Like, "Bishounen Tanteidan" wasn't matched at all in the 2nd or 3rd attempt. Again, it's okay to have items left out since it can't be perfectly matched, but I want it to be consistent.

Comment: Welcome to So! Do you have a (small, hopefully) example that shows the randomness? I checked the code, too, and it looks like you are right to expect same output from the matching function for same input.

Comment: @VirtualScooter Thanks for replying. I edited in some example results I'm getting. The lists of nodes and edges don't have anything special, besides maybe being a bit long (53 and 64 nodes, with 350 edges), but I don't think it's big enough to cause issues.